# Journey exit criteria

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I know about the goal criteria of a journey. I see this basically as a success-exit-criteria. I also know that a user is always validated after a wait etc. against that goal. But I also want the contact to exit the journey for example if the contact has a "cancel" flag. How to achieve this without doing a decision split all the time? Is there any exit criteria next to the goal criteria that basically does the same? Originally I would have expected that after a wait a contact is also validated against the "Contact Entry Settings" next to the goal settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER *(includes information from August '17 release):***

Just recently Salesforce added an "Exit Criteria" feature which can be configured just the way goals are defined, but don't compromise your goal attainment statistics anymore. The exit criteria are evaluated on every completed wait activity.

> When a contact meets any of the exit filter criteria upon leaving a wait activity, the contact is removed from the journey.

*How to define exit criteria?*

The exit criteria can be defined in the wizard, that can be launched using the exit-icon on the top right of the journey canvas. Expressions can be defined using Expression Builder that is known from decision splits and goal criteria.

**Related documentation:**

- [Define Exit Criteria](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/exit_criteria/define_exit_criteria/)

**Original answer (outdated):**

<strike>Unfortunately there isn't currently. Therefore you need to either:</strike>

- Modify your journey goal (which compromises your real goal attainment statistics)
- Add a lot of decision splits to your journey
- (if you just need to stop emails from being sent) add an exclusion script to your send email activities that filter the subscriber out

Comment: Okay. I will add it to the Idea board

Comment: Actually, yes it is possible. http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/exit_criteria/define_exit_criteria/

Comment: @Ado Sorry for that and thanks for pointing this out! This has just been added in the last release and hasn't been possible before. I updated my answer to include all valid information.